Start and withdrawl remix problem. High fee
I have a remix problem with a smart contract. When i press start start i get this error messageGas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"gas required exceeds allowance (8431)","id":7292519833806330} and when i press withdrawl i get this error Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"gas required exceeds allowance (8052)","id":7292519833806268} it allso says that the fee is super high? whats wrong? it says fee for transfer is Alert
0.0738 ETH
194,28 US$

Can you share the code?
